# No module named urllib in IronPython in Asp.net

Tags: python, asp.net, ironpython

I am trying to integrate python script on my asp function by executing it.

here is my code

```
var options = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        options["Frames"] = true;
        options["FullFrames"] = true;
        ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine(options);                               

        ICollection<string> paths = engine.GetSearchPaths();
        string dir = @"C:\Python27\Lib\";
        paths.Add(dir);
        string dir2 = @"C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages";
        paths.Add(dir2);

        engine.SetSearchPaths(paths);

        ScriptSource source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile("C:/Dave/jirautomatic/try.py");
        ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();
        source.Execute(scope);
        dynamic Generate = scope.GetVariable("connect_to_jira_and_get_projects");
        dynamic gen = Generate();
        gen();
```

Based on what I've read, to use the library of python I need to use Get and SetSearchPath.

I included the library path of Python2.7 but unfortunately it returns

> No module named urllib

but on the library urllib is included.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: what happens when you run the python file directly from a command line?

Comment: you mean using process function? unfortunately it just pop up the command line but the expected csv file is not created.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'using process function'.  If your python code doesn't work from the command line, debug it first.